# EF 4.1 Code First - wrap multiple calls to SaveChanges in a transaction

Tags: transactions, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

For reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936880/ef-code-fist-4-1-how-to-configure-one-to-many-relationship-with-default/5940818#5940818) I need to make multiple calls to SaveChanges.  I would like both of these calls to be wrapped up in a transaction (so that if the second call fails, the first call will roll back).  For example:

```
AccountsContext context = new AccountsContext(connectionString);

CountryNotes notes = new CountryNotes();
notes.Notes = "First save";
context.SaveChanges();

notes.Notes = "Second save";
context.SaveChanges();
```

How do I put the above two calls to SaveChanges in a single transaction?

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TransactionScope`:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    AccountsContext context = new AccountsContext(connectionString);

    CountryNotes notes = new CountryNotes();
    notes.Notes = "First save";
    context.SaveChanges();

    notes.Notes = "Second save";
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: So to do this I would need to enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC - at least that's what the exception is telling me when I try this code.  I would like to avoid this if possible as it will require more configuration changes for user sites.